# Javascript to adjust sidebar width % depending on screen size

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a sidebar in my project which pushes out on a click event and what I would like to achieve is to have the sidebar push out to different width sizes depending on the size of the users screen.

i.e.:

if the user is on a screen of a width of 768px and above the side bar will push out by a width of 20%.

if the user is on a screen of 767px and below the sidebar will push out by a width of 95%.

I have tried the following code below, however, it is not working in the correct way and is pushing the sidebar width to 20% regardless of the screen size.

If anyone can help, that would be awesome!

```
 <a>
  <i class="sideNavBars fas fa-bars fa-2x" onclick="openNav()"></i>
</a>

<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav text-center">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <div>
   <p>Sidebar content</p>
  </div>
</dvi>


if ($(window).width() > 739) {
  function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "20%";
    document.getElementById("sideBarWrapper").style.marginRight = "20%";
  }
}
else {
  function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "95%";
    document.getElementById("sideBarWrapper").style.marginRight = "95%";
  }
}
```

Comment: you could use css only too. Maybe share more of your code.

Comment: Any particular reason why you're not using css media queries instead?

Comment: are you using some framework or plain css

Comment: The sidebar is initially set at a width of 0% and then is extended by the click of a button.  As the sidebar is initially set to a width of 0% I can not see how I would be able to amend the width depending on the users' screen other than using JavaScript.  If there is a way to achieve this through CSS that would be great but not sure how I can achieve this :(

Answer (score 0):

Give your sidebar a class (here is `.sidenav`) and add Media Queries:

```
.sidenav {
    display: none;
}

@media(min-width: 768px){
    #mySidenav {
        width: 20%;
    }
}

@media(max-width: 767px){
    #mySidenav {
        width: 95%;
    }
}
```

Then add this piece of code:

```
openNav() {
    var sidebar = document.getElementById("sideNav");
    sidebar.classList.toggle("sidenav");
}
```

See: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp

and: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_class.asp